# Why do divs lose their ability to output at % when inside other divs?

Tags: html, css, pixel, percentage, element

Why do `<divs>` lose their ability to output width and height at % (percentages) when they're inside other `<divs>`?

I have `<div id="2">` and `<div id="3">` inside `<div id="1">`.

`<div id="1">`'s width and height are set with % (percentage).

How come `<div id="2">` and `<div id="3">` height don't work when I set them to %?  (They work with px (pixels) though.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` in div1 them only inner div's will take % height and div with respect to parent

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}
#div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f00;
  height: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#div2 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #0f0;
  height: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#div3 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #00f;
  height: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` is relative unit of measurement so you need to set any parent to absolute unit like `px`
for example if your `div1` is empty then div1 has `100% width and 0% height` in this case your `div2 and div3` will not work.

set your html, body width and height to 100% and your all div should work properly
try this code;

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

.div1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.div2{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #888;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.div3{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[**SEE WORKING EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/myz1s4yv/)